# What is this hotspot doing to my traffic?

Tags: wifi

I'm currently staying at a Four Seasons resort using their Wifi. I noticed that while surfing all non-https sites, my webpage seems to be forced into a frame.  For example, here is what google's homepage (over http) looks like on the hotspot:

```
<frameset id="frameset1" name="frameset1" rows="35,*" framespacing="0" frameborder="0">
<frame name="top" scrolling="NO" src="http://google.com/?d96a349c52fc4f68eea46a47ccb3d361=http://p1846.superclick.com//std/fourseasons_tiered_new/toolbar.php?noframe_url=http://p1846.superclick.com/superclick/noiframes.php?url=http://google.com/&">
<frame name="main" scrolling="YES" src="http://google.com/?d96a349c52fc4f68eea46a47ccb3d360"> 
</frameset>
<noframes><body>
Frames are required, for this page to display correctly.
<a href="http://p1846.superclick.com/superclick/noiframes.php?url=http://google.com/">Click here to continue to the requested page</a>
</body></noframes>
```

My guess is that they're basically tracking my internet traffic through a third-party (superclick) for advertising purposes.. can anyone perhaps more versed in the area offer some more insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are very close; but checking out superclick.com, seems like its being done for network monitoring and management purposes.

http://www.superclick.com/mama-analytics